# Why cant I use std::copy with std::string to another std::string?

Tags: c++

The following code prints an empty string and i am unable to understand why it is so?

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s="hello";
    std::string r;
    std::copy(s.rbegin(),s.rend(), r.begin());
    std::cout<<r;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No i am not looking to copy to a vector of chars. I am looking at copying the string to another string. I am aware of other string copying mechanisms but i expected this to work as well.

Comment: `std::copy` doesn't allocate memory. You have the resize the container. You can `std::string r(s.length(), '\0');`

Comment: Because `r` is empty, and the only thing that can be copied into an empty string is another empty string. Is there any specific reason why `r=s;` will not work for you?

Comment: There's also a constructor for `std::string` that uses iterators. You can do `std::string r(s.rbegin(), s.rend());` to get this effect, bypassing `std::copy`.

Comment: @sam varshachik i was doing it more as a learning experience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `r` is an empty `std::string`, it contains no `char`s. `std::copy` is trying to copy-assign `char`s since `r.begin()`, which leads to UB.

You can make `r` containing 5 elements in advance.

```
std::string r(5, '\0');
```

Or

```
std::string r;
r.resize(5);
```

Or use `std::back_inserter`.

```
std::string r;
std::copy(s.rbegin(),s.rend(), std::back_inserter(r));
```